# Series expansion of a multivariate function

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am going through "[The mathematics of Brownian motion and Johnson noise](https://zenodo.org/record/1236118/files/article.pdf)" by Daniel T.Gillespie and in the second page, he has :
[image]

I couldn't figure out how he expanded $A(X(t+\frac{1}{2}dt),t+\frac{1}{2}dt)$ to get equation $2.3d$

He is trying to show how a process defined by:
$$ X(t+dt) = x(t) + A(X(t),t)dt$$
is self-consistent and how a process defined by:
$$ X(t+dt) = x(t) + A(X(t),t)(dt)^\frac{1}{2}$$
is inconsistent.